# What's the git equivalent of this Mercurial action to initialize and upload a repo?

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket

In Mercurial, I usually do this:

```
hg init
hg addremove
hg commit -m "init repo"
hg push https://arezzo:mypassword@bitbucket.org/arezzo/mynewrepo
```

I tried something similar in git and it didn't work:

```
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "init repo"
git push https://arezzo:mypassword@bitbucket.org/arezzo/mynewrepo
```

The message I get after `push` is:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Nothing gets pushed to bitbucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't specify a branch to push when you're using `git push`, it by default will only push branches where a branch with the same name exists in the remote repository.  In this case, I guess that this is the first time that you're pushing to this repository, so there is no branch called `master` yet - thus, `git push URL` doesn't push anything.

Another tip that may be useful is that you usually create a `remote` as a short name for the repository URL when you're using git.  So, to modify your steps slightly, try the following instead:

```
mkdir mynewrepo
cd mynewrepo

git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin https://arezzo:mypassword@bitbucket.org/arezzo/mynewrepo
git push -u origin master
```

Then you can use `origin` in place of the URL.  You only need to use the `-u` option the first time that you push - it just sets up some helpful default config options so that `git pull` works without additional arguments, for instance.

Comment: Thanks! And would each subsequent push use the `push` syntax you used: `git push -u origin master`? What would happen if I used `git push https://arezzo:mypassword@bitbucket.org/arezzo/mynewrepo` for subsequent `push`s?

Comment: Using the full URL would work now that `master` exists in the remote repository.  However, for subsequent pushes, I would just do: `git push origin master`, since you don't need the `-u` more than once, and I think the default behaviour of `git push origin` and `git push` is confusing.  It's better to explicitly say which branch you want to push.

Comment: Thank you. One more thing: So `origin` is the name of the branch and `master` is the name of . . . what? The remote branch?

Comment: No, origin is an alias for the URL of the repository (the remote name), and master is the name of the branch, which you want to push.